# How to turn off ESlinting newline in VS code

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I have an open and saved file in VS code:
[image: Open saved file]

Now if I, for an example, make this line longer by adding some in-line styles, the line is automatically formatted and broken up into multiple lines upon saving the file:
[image: Automated multiple lines]

I am not interested in this. I would like to avoid the single '>' char being on it´s own line, and the line breaking to take place after at least the double amount of characters per line.
As far as I can see, this auto-formatting is happening because of ESLint which is included in the project. In the ESLint documentation [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) I can´t find any newline settings which affects this problem. And neither  cant I find any settings in VS code File > Preferences > Settings which relates to it.

So how to turn off this quite annoying problem?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the sample problem, and this is helping me solve the problem.
On the VSCode>file->preference->setting in the search box, searching the word with "Line Length" then change the value to whatever you want :)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not have any effect in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is due to eslint, you need to check vscode html formatter : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

Comment: I´ve tried to play around with the html.format.wrapLineLength setting, but it doesent change anything. Also tried to put "html.format.enable": false in the settings.json file, but nothing changes.The line still breaks when the file is saved.

Comment: Is it a pure html file or something like jsx/react file? If you set it to false, you can use any other formatter that you want and play with its settings

Comment: It´s a .vue file. And I´m using vetur+prettier to format these files (found out that right now), but it still doesent change anything if I disable vetur and prettier :/
I´ll try and look for another formatter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a prettier Extension,

1. open "Prettier - Code formatter"
2. click the "setting" which is next to "uninstall" button, when you click you see
   four options. from that select "Extension setting"
3. on 3rd step, you have 2 option "user" and "workspace". select one of them. under this find "Prettier: Print Width". when you get this, change the number like 150. by default it is 80.
   This is work for sure.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not have any effect in my case.